# Can I use tab(\t) in cookies?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I am setting cookies as following.

```
document.cookie = name+ "=" + value+ "; " + exdays+ ";path=/";
```

Cookies values is "US\tNY".
Means I am using \t to split Us and Ny.
But after using \t ,it's not saving data in cookie.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to urlencode (encodeURIComponent) the data of the cookie in order to save the tab control character.